# Is it necessary to set auto_bootstrap to false when adding a new datacenter?

Tags: cassandra

I am preparing the documentation for another Cassandra cluster in a new datacenter and wonder how the bootstrap process of the seed nodes and non seed nodes should be done.
For the most part I am following the steps from [this](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2019/02/26/data-center-switch.html) blog.

Currently the cluster is on version 3.11.5 and the official documentation says nothing about the `auto_bootstrap` setting when setting up a new DC.

When I boot the nodes in the new DC one by one, I don't want to stream any data yet (keyspace has already been adjusted so that the new DC has replication factor 0). Shouldn't I rather set the `auto_bootstrap` setting to `false` or do I not understand something correctly?

In the Cassandra 2.2 documentation, it is explicitly pointed out that the setting should be set to false.

I hope I was able to explain my understanding problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a new DC, you don't need to worry about setting that property one way or another. This is because when nodes are bootstrapped, they will only stream data from their ***local*** data center. As your data center is new, there isn't any data to stream. So in this case, it doesn't matter what that property is set to; no data will be streamed either way.

Therefore, follow the steps as described, and just be sure to run step #9 of

```
nodetool rebuild original_data_center_name_here
```

...on *each* node. That's the step that will bring data in from another DC.

Comment: Thanks! I missed somehow the little hint that it's about streaming data locally.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessary to set `auto_bootstrap: false` in `cassandra.yaml` provided there are no replicas configured in the new DC.

When adding a new DC, it is necessary to re-configure keyspaces such that all keyspaces with replication set to `SimpleStrategy` should be switched to `NetworkTopologyStrategy` with replicas configured in the existing DC(s) using the `ALTER KEYSPACE` command. For example:

```
ALTER KEYSPACE app_ks
  WITH REPLICATION = {
    'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'existingDC: 3'
  };
```

This must be done BEFORE adding a new DC. Also note that you should NOT change the replication settings for system keyspaces which have been configured with `LocalStrategy` since those contain data specific to a node and should not be replicated to other nodes. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, we have kept that in mind. There are only two system keyspaces that still need to be converted to `NetworkTopologyStrategy` from `SimpleStrategy`. Is an ALTER KEYSPACE sufficient or do we have to do a repair or something similar afterwards?